# Difficulty plotting a complex-valued function

Tags: plotting, complex

```
R3=2 Re[Sqrt[(1/173) (z + I*1.4)]]-2*(4/3)*(-Pi/2 - Arg[Sqrt[(1/173)(z + I 1.4)]]) -
       2*(4/3) Im[PolyGamma[1 - I*(4/6) Sqrt[(1/173)(z + I 1.4)]]]
```

This is the function I am trying to plot with z between 330 and 360. However I don't see a plot; only the axis.

Comment: I peek at `Table[R3,{z,330,360}]` and it shows me `0.4 I1` in each of those. If I look at your expression carefully I notice there isn't a space or `*` between `I` and `1.4` at the beginning. I stick an `*` or a space in there and your plot shows up fine.